# Assembly multiply simplification?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64, elf

In the post [Say Hello to Assembly - Part 3](https://0xax.blogspot.com/2014/09/say-hello-to-x64-assembly-part-3.html) the author wants to print a string (converted integer) on the stack.  `r12` contains the number of digits in the string.

```
;;; Find length of string
mov rax, 1                    
mul r12
mov r12, 8                    ; 8 times num digits to get len in bytes
mul r12
mov rdx, rax                  ; length of string int rdx


;;;; print sum
mov rax, SYS_WRITE
mov rdi, STD_OUT
mov rsi, rsp
syscall
```

My question is can we simplify to:

```
;;; Find length of string
mov rax, 8                    ; 8 times num digits
mul r12
mov rdx, rax                  ; length of string int rdx
```

Or is there something subtle about the author's method that I am missing?

To me is looks like he is putting 1 in `rax` multiplying by `r12` then putting 8 in `r12` and then multiplying again.  My method seems cleaner and seems to work.

Comment: Note that rdx must be the length of the string in rsi for the SYS_WRITE call.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is equivalent, but why not just

```
imul rdx,r12,8
```

or alternatively (though perhaps a fatter opcode)

```
lea rdx,[r12*8]
```

Comment: Both instructions are four bytes long.

Comment: I see the `imul rdx,r12,8` as four bytes, but the `lea rdx,[r12*8]` seems to be 8 bytes since there is no base register.  If it were something like `lea rdx,[rax+r12*8]` the lea would be 4 bytes.

Comment: Oh yeah, I totally forgot. And `imul` is quite fast too on modern platforms, perhaps just as fast as a `lea` with a sib operand.

Comment: `LEA` is still faster than `IMUL`, even on modern processors, but it's a pretty close call. The only compiler that you will ever see generating `IMUL` in these cases is Clang, and I don't know why it does this. If you can throw in a base register, `LEA` is a *decisive* win. It would also be worth investigating `SHL`+`MOV`, especially on modern processors (Haswell and later) where `MOV`s are elided by the front end via renaming.